# why is this while loop condition true

Tags: java, while-loop

Given is the following code:

```
public class tester {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int a = 0;
    while(a == a++) {
        a++;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

}
```

My question is, why would this print out all even numbers, starting from 2?

Why does it even go through the while loop?
The condition in the very beginning: if a is equal to a+1: but 0 is not equal to 1.

That's at least my thoughts on this. Any proper answer?

Comment: `a == a++` **is not the same as** `a == ++a`! `a == a++ === true`

Comment: read more about post and pre increment

Comment: *"if a is equal to a+1"* - That's *not* what that condition says.  It says "if a is equal to a (and then add 1 to a afterward)"

Answer (score 4):

You must consider what `a++` does - first it returns the value of `a` to be used in the calculation. Then it increments `a`. So `a == a++` is ALWAYS true. By comparison, `a == ++a` which does the increment *before* it returns the value to be used in the calculation, is NEVER true.

From there, you then increment `a` again. So each loop it's being incremented twice, which is why you see even numbers and never odd.

Comment: Consider `while(condition) { execute; }` the condition is always evaluated, but the execute is not always evaluated. If you want to guarantee one execution, you need to say [`do { execute; } while (condition);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)